# converting latex to maxima using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, latex, maxima

I'm currently using `mathquill.js` to build a math keyboard and display. im using `mathquill.js` to generate the tex value of the expression but the math engine on the server side is maxima. I am looking for a "client side" way to translate tex to maxima so I can send to the maxima engine directly from the client without the need to fiddle with the server.

Anyone know of a js library that can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a JavaScript library called TeX2Max for converting LaTeX math into Maxima code. It has been designed with [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com) in mind. It is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/KQMATH/tex2max) or as an [NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tex2max).

Hope this helps anyone still looking for a solution to this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Maxima doesn't understand LaTeX as input, but it can understand content MathML via the maximaMathML share package. So if you could export content MathML from mathquill.js, you could use that as input to Maxima. If you can only export LaTeX from mathquill.js, you'll have to convert it somehow. See the responses to [this question about parsing LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4223/what-parsers-for-latex-mathematics-exist-outside-of-the-tex-engines).

If you end up working with content MathML, I can help you with the maximaMathML package.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to install maximaMathML?

Comment: You can say `load(maximaMathML);` to load the package. The usual read-eval-print loop is replaced with a loop that reads Maxima input and prints the result as presentation mathml and content mathml. In order to read content mathml input, you can call the function `mathml();` which appears to read one content mathml expression and then prints the output as presentation and content mathml. I think it would straightforward to modify the read-eval-print loop to have a different behavior, e.g., always read content mathml and only output content mathml, or some other combination.

Comment: Could you point to any example? I have loaded the package but have no clue how to use it, unfortunately. In Maple I have to Paste the MathML and it will be rendered automatically.

Comment: I don't know any examples, you can try entering, say `diff(x^3, x);` to see the result as presentation and content mathml. To try the input mode, enter `mathml();` and then copy and paste some content mathml. To generate some nontrivial content mathml for input, try entering `'(diff(x^3, x));` i.e. quote the expression to prevent evaluation, so it remains unevaluated in the result. This is all pretty clumsy, but as I was saying, it's going to be straightforward to figure out a different input-output loop.